# Filter data from session in laravel

Tags: laravel

My requirement is to filter data from the session array using a search keyword.

```
return $excelData->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($request) {
    return substr($value['3'], 0, strlen($request['key'])) === strtoupper($request['key']);
});
```

This is working fine when I search a letter or number. But my issue is it only search from the starting letter of data. My requirement is, if I search a word, get the result that have anywhere in the search key.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stristr` to find first occurrence of the string (case insensitive).

```
return $excelData->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($request) {     
    return stristr ($value['3'] , strtoupper($request['key'])) ;
});
```

or if you want to return whole value:

```
return $excelData->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($request) {     
    if(stristr ($value['3'] , strtoupper($request['key'])) !== false){
      return $value;
    }
});
```